# index.js:1 Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This was my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    invites: [],
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/security/allUser`).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      this.setState({ invites: res.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.invites.map((invite) => (
          <h2 key={invite.id}>{invite.name}</h2>
        ))}
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

state and setState have worked for me alright for more complex codes before. This one keeps showing the same error

This is the error:

index.js:1 Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the App component.

Comment: You are not allow to make requests or update state inside constructor. Use `componentDidMount` instead. Just remove constructor and move axios code to `componentDidMount`

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked

Answer (score 2):

Add a `componentDidMount()` and write your request call inside it. When the component first loads the `componentDidMount` function will run.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can make request in constructor (React allows it but you shouldnt) but you have to make the request only after the component has been mounted or just before it is about to be mounted.

So it is wise to make your requests in componentDidMount().

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       invites: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/security/allUser`).then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          this.setState({ invites: res.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.invites.map((invite) => (
          <h2 key={invite.id}>{invite.name}</h2>
        ))}
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```